# an element's position moves when entered text

Tags: html, css

I have made a `<div>` with a left border and a menu bar that on click on one of the options it looks like the menu is over the  the `<div>`.

now, when there is text in the `div` (I need it to have text) it moves to the left.

jsFiddles:
[without text](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/61/) , [with text](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/62/)

here is the code:(i need to have the text inside the second `div`)

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; top:39px; right:70%;">
   <div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
   </div>
   <div id='settingNev' style="position:relative; top:300px;">
     <ul>
       <li id="Li1" runat="server" class="active">
          <a id="A2" runat="server"><span>Resume</span></a>
       </li>
       <li id="Li2" runat="server">
          <a id="A3" runat="server"><span>Freinds </span></a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

how can I fix it so that the style will be the same, so I could enter text into the `div`. (I don't want to have the `div` `width:0px;` because then the text would go out of the `div`, breaking the lines after each word like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/63/)

Thanks for the help

Comment: You mean you want something like this? http://jsbin.com/neqon/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your last solution where width is set to 0px and to fix the word wrap you can just u white-space:nowrap like this:

`<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1; width:0px; white-space:nowrap">`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/84/

However, this is not a very nice way to fix the problem, but your css in the jsfiddle is so messy that I don't know which css you do or don't need.. Try to clean up your css. I made a clean version myself, but possibly deleted css you still needed: http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/101/

Answer (score 1):

Place the border on the right hand side of the element?

```
<div style="border-right:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
```